# cloud hosting with ability to mount in unix platform

Tags: cloud-hosting

as the title states...i would like to push the images of my gallery to the cloud...but i need to have access to them through the filesystem rather than an API.

Can anybody recommend any good providers?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [s3fs](https://fedorahosted.org/s3fs/) along with Amazon's S3 before. It seems to work okay, but is a fair amount slower than accessing the remote data via traditional methods.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Flickr](http://flickr.com/) accessed via [flickrfs](http://manishrjain.googlepages.com/flickrfs)? More generally, as long as your operating system supports [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) (Linux, *BSD, Mac OS X, Solaris), you have a wide choice of access methods, including [FTP](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net), [ssh](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), [WebDAV](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/fusedav/), [Wikimedia](http://wikipediafs.sourceforge.net/), …